# boost::ptr_vector vs. std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, vector

They do the similar things.

What should be considered when choosing between the two?

Under which circumstances is either one preferred?

Comment: I think you need to ask for something more objective than "better".

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "better". The latter doesn't require external dependencies, but the former may be simpler to use (depending on your definition of "simpler" :]).

Comment: Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469968/stl-container-with-stdunique-ptrs-vs-boostptr-container

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/1374840/318716

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` for several reasons:

1. Type safety -- while this is pretty well abstracted for you in `boost::ptr_vector`, `ptr_vector` is still implemented in terms of `std::vector<void*>`.
2. Clear support for custom deleter -- I think you can get custom deleter behavior with a `boost::ptr_vector`, but the support is clearer (and explicit) when using `std::unique_ptr`.
3. It's standard, and well supported by compliant C++11 compilers.

Comment: I would also add that `vector<unique_ptr>` is _standard_. People know what it is. Most people probably don't know `boost::ptr_vector`